# Which git-lfs does `git lfs` use?

Tags: git, git-lfs, git-for-windows

I've just updated my installed Git LFS from https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/releases to the latest version (2.3.0). However, when I run `git lfs version` I see:

```
$ git lfs version
git-lfs/2.2.1 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.8.3; git 621d1f82)
```

If I run `git-lfs version` I see the new version:

```
$ git-lfs version
git-lfs/2.3.0 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.8.3; git 4dd2bf73)
```

I'm not sure I understand where the `git lfs` command finds its git-lfs. I've hunted down a couple (or at least one) old git-lfs installation and deleted them, though git still seems to find an old one. And there's no other git-lfs in the path.

What would I need to do to tell git to use the newly installed version?

I'm running Windows 10 and using Cygwin. I get the same in PowerShell and cmd.

**EDIT:**
I found this:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git-lfs.exe
```

and this seems to be the old version:

```
$ /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/bin/git-lfs.exe version
git-lfs/2.2.1 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.8.3; git 621d1f82)
```

Should I just delete this (and the other should be found via the `PATH`, or replace it with the new one? Or is there a more "official" way of doing this?

Comment: As a general rule, `git asdf` searches `$PATH` for a program named `git-asdf`. Whichever one it finds first, it runs. It adds the built in git-core directory (from `git --exec-path`) at the front of `$PATH` first, since most `git-whatever` code lives there. So, whichever `git-lfs` is first in your augmented `$PATH` is probably the one used. But Git-for-Windows might be different.

Comment: I guess it must be. `git --exec-path` gives me `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core`, which doesn't contain git-lfs, but maybe it's also doing something windows-ey to get the mingw64 in its path...

Comment: @torek Would you like to write your comment as an answer, so I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a rule, when you run any arbitrary command that Git doesn't know as a built-in (or even one that Git *does* know as a built-in, really) such as:

```
git asdf
```

Git will search your `$PATH` for a program named `git-asdf`.  Before doing this search, though, Git inserts its built-in git-core directory:

```
$ git --exec-path
/usr/lib/git-core
```

(on an Ubuntu VM; on my Mac it's currently `/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.15.1_1/libexec/git-core` since that's the last update I installed there).

Among other things, this means you can write your own Git commands and put them somewhere in your `$PATH`.  But in this case it means that `git lfs ...` probably finds either `$(git --exec-path)/git-lfs`, or whatever your shell says if you run:

```
$ which git-lfs
```

assuming, of course, that you have a shell that supports this.

Per your edit, I would imagine that `git --exec-path` produces `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin`.

> Should I just delete this (and the other should be found via the PATH, or replace it with the new one? Or is there a more "official" way of doing this?

Deleting it will probably work.  I foresee two main dangers of simply deleting the one in the `git-core` directory:

- Sometimes Git and/or various things that work like plug-ins evolve at different paces.  If there is a paired version of `git-lfs` that is known to work with that particular Git installation, some other `git-lfs` might not work because it might be out of sync.  (So you might save it away in a third location, out of the way, rather than just removing it.)
- Something might re-install the old one automatically, or de-install the new one.  The former is just annoying while the latter would lead to failures (so having the old one saved away could be handy).

Comment: Thank you! :)
`git-lfs` (as `which git-lfs` indeed reveals) points to `/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git LFS/git-lfs`, which makes sense as `/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git LFS` is the first (non-cygwin) entry in my PATH.
`git --exec-path` actually points to `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core` which doesn't seem to contain a `git-lfs`, but the path you suggest (`C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin`) does, and that seems to be the git-lfs that's being run, and removing it (I just renamed it to old_version_of_git-lfs.exe) fixed the issue :)